Permanent files using <Files> using Wix v5
I am using Wix V5 to create a MSI installer. I use the <Files> to harvest files, and I would like to have them permanent, meaning it's not removed at uninstall. I only see the possibility to do it on a <Component> but can't use Files in a Component. So how I could achieve this ? I would like to do something like this : <Files Include="A/B/**" Permanent="yes" /> I already check the documentation but didn't notice any argument I could use to set the files harvested as permanent one.

Do you happen to be using a bootstrapper with a bundle?

Use the Component element. The Files element does not support the less-used attributes of the Component and File elements.

I would like to use the <Component> element but I can't use the <Files> element inside, it's not a valid child. I tried but got an error, so how I should do ?

Create a Component element per-file.

Ok which mean I can't use the auto harvest of the <Files> element, because I was using  to harvest a whole folder and not specify by hand each single file. That's a bit sad

It is not a core scenario to harvest a bunch of permanent files. So, yes, it is more work on your end to support such an uncommon scenario.

I have the same issue. In 3.x I was using Heat to harvest and had to use a XSLT transform to add the Permanent="yes" to the harvested files. But we are now being forced to target Dot.Net Framework 4.8.1 in order to support Arm64 processors and we couldn't do that in WiX 3.11 so upgraded to v5 and switched to Files because our Heat code no longer worked.
In our case we ship sample data files and tutorials (all generated by non-devs) and harvest them because they change frequently and maintaining the install to drop old ones and add new ones would be a lot of work. They are installed in the Program Data folder and end users can use them and come to rely on them so removing them would be a problem. Long term users will have lots of samples that no longer ship.
I don't think this is all that unusual a situation as I have seen similar at every company I've worked at. Sure, it would be possible to not ship/install any samples and force the user to download them from a website, but then they have to go looking for them whereas those that are on there system just appear in our product ready to use.
